# Is there a skeleton project for a graphical cross-platform Python application?

Tags: python, qt, cross-platform, py2exe, py2app

I found that making a Python application work across all three platforms with, say, PySide is hard enough work as it is. Surely there's a project that provides an example codebase where this all works (even packaging the application and deploying it as well)

Comment: did you try [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? note the doc says it doesnt work with 3.x but it out of date, their website says it works fine with 3.x

Comment: That is not a skeleton project. No I have no used cx_freeze.

Comment: Seems to be a good example of a cross-platform app https://shanetully.com/2013/08/cross-platform-deployment-of-python-applications-with-pyinstaller/

Answer (score 0):

You could use PyInstaller. The development version works with OSX and the older versions work with all linux distributions i have tried (ubuntu/debian, opensuse,...)

Just have a look at it, works fine for me [www.pyinstaller.org](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)